# MS Azure Oryx Pre Build Command

Tags: python, django, azure

Trying to add a Oryx Pre Build Command for `apt-get` package as per the documentation found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/master/doc/configuration.md)

I added the command as an App Setting in the Azure App Service Portal, but when the project builds, it doesn't run the command. Did I place the command in the correct location?
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Facing the same issue here